# Remove rows from Spark DataFrame that ONLY satisfy two conditions

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am using Scala and Spark. I want to filter out certain rows from a DataFrame that do NOT satisfy ALL the conditions that I am specifying, while keeping other rows that might only one of the conditions be satisfied.

For example: let's say I have this DataFrame

```
+-------+----+
|country|date|
+-------+----+
|      A|   1|
|      A|   2|
|      A|   3|
|      B|   1|
|      B|   2|
|      B|   3|
+-------+----+
```

and I want to filter out country `A` and dates `1` and `2`, so that the expected output should be:

```
+-------+----+
|country|date|
+-------+----+
|      A|   3|
|      B|   1|
|      B|   2|
|      B|   3|
+-------+----+
```

As you can see, I am still keeping country `B` with dates `1` and `2`.

I tried to use `filter` in the following way

```
df.filter("country != 'A' and date not in (1,2)")
```

But the output filters out all dates 1, and 2, which is not what I want.

Thanks.

Comment: Your condition is wrong. You probably want `"country != 'A' or date not in (1,2)"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your current condition is

```
df.filter("country != 'A' and date not in (1,2)")
```

which can be translated as "accept any country other than A, *then* accept any date except 1 or 2". Your conditions are applied independently

What you want is:

```
df.filter("not (country = 'A' and date in (1,2))")
```

i.e. "Find the rows with country A and date of 1 or 2, and reject them"

or equivalently:

```
df.filter("country != 'A' or date not in (1,2)")
```

i.e. "If country isn't A, then accept it regardless of the date. If the country is A, then the date mustn't be 1 or 2"

See [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws):

> not(A or B) = not A and not B
>
> not (A and B) = not A or not B

Comment: That worked just fine. Thank you for the detailed explanation!